# How to do join with dynamic numbers of view

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with multiple answer of survey data, which each brand has its own variables with multiple images with delimited format is respondents answer more than 1 image.

Example:

```
RespondentsID | Q_Brand_1 | Q_Brand_2
--------------+-----------+----------
     001      |    2      | 1;2;3;4
     002      |    2;3    | 1
     003      |    1;4    | 1;2
```

What I need is to make this in unstacked (binary) to be applied on our internal software. Something like this:

```
RespID | [Brand 1 - Imagery 1] | [Brand 1 - Imagery 2] | [Brand 1 - Imagery 3] | [Brand 1 - Imagery 4] | [Brand 2 - Imagery 1] | [Brand 2 - Imagery 2] | [Brand 2 - Imagery 3] | [Brand 2 - Imagery 4] 

001 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1

002 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0

003 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
```

I tried to stacked the data first using fn_split function and then do dynamic pivot to unstacked it. But i found that those only works for 1 brand, to do it for multiple brand, I need to join it with first query

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Text]) 
                    from [dbo].[tbl_Imagery_Reference]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
     = 'SELECT a.RespondentsID, ' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            SELECT a.SERIAL, b.Text as Imagery, 1 as Value
            FROM [dbo].[Raw_Data_Imagery_Stacked] as a
            left join [dbo].[tbl_Reference_Imagery] as b
            on a.Items = b.Precode
            where Brand = ''Brand A''
         ) x
         pivot 
         (
            AVG(Value)
            for Imagery in (' + @cols + ')
         ) p 
         right join Raw_Data as a
         on a.SERIAL = p.SERIAL
         '

execute ('create view dbo.vw_Imagery_unstacked as ' + @Query)
```

I except to have a query to generate sets of imagery of multiple brands dynamically.

Comment: so what is your output getting from above query.

Comment: Also you are using 2 tables `Raw_Data_Imagery_Stacked` and `tbl_Reference_Imagery`, please share the schema of both tables.

Comment: The result of those query are generate 1 set of image for 1 brand. Regarding the tables, Raw Data Imagery Stacked are used for stacked data from columnar raw data to row model, while Reference Imagery are used for "Text" which our raw data only stored data with code / number

Answer (score 2):

My script will work in any `version` of `sql server`.

```
SELECT  RespondentsID, [Brand 1 - Imagery 1], [Brand 1 - Imagery 2], [Brand 1 - Imagery 3], [Brand 1 - Imagery 4],
ISNULL([Q21], 0) AS [Brand 2 - Imagery 1], ISNULL([Q22], 0) AS [Brand 2 - Imagery 2],
ISNULL([Q23], 0) AS [Brand 2 - Imagery 3], ISNULL([Q24], 0) AS [Brand 2 - Imagery 4]
FROM    ( SELECT    RespondentsID , ISNULL([1], 0) AS [Brand 1 - Imagery 1] , ISNULL([2], 0) AS [Brand 1 - Imagery 2] ,
ISNULL([3], 0) AS [Brand 1 - Imagery 3] , ISNULL([4], 0) AS [Brand 1 - Imagery 4] ,
                    'Q2' + Q2Value AS Q2Value
          FROM      ( SELECT distinct RespondentsID ,
                                Q1.Value AS Q1Value ,
                                Q2.Value AS Q2Value
                      FROM      @ActivityLog BS
                                OUTER APPLY (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Value 
                                            FROM (SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(Q_Brand_1, ';', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String) AS A
                                            CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)) Q1
                                OUTER APPLY (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Value 
                                            FROM (SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(Q_Brand_2, ';', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String) AS A
                                            CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)) Q2
                    ) Src PIVOT ( COUNT(Q1Value) FOR Q1Value IN ( [1], [2],
                                                              [3], [4] ) ) Pv
        ) S2 PIVOT ( COUNT(Q2Value) FOR Q2Value IN ( [Q21], [Q22], [Q23],
                                                     [Q24] ) ) Pv2;
```

To check the query output **[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bc18b049eae1c60e18ff9c87340f6563)**

If you are using `SqlServer 2016+ version` then you can use built-in function named **`string_split`** instead of `Sub query`.

**Code**,

```
OUTER APPLY string_split(Q_Brand_1, ';') Q1
OUTER APPLY string_split(Q_Brand_2, ';') Q2
```

instead of

```
OUTER APPLY (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Value 
                                            FROM (SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(Q_Brand_1, ';', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String) AS A
                                            CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)) Q1

OUTER APPLY (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Value 
                                            FROM (SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(Q_Brand_2, ';', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String) AS A
                                            CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)) Q2
```

Comment: @ Pawan, This is really very nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost on right track.You need to pivot it one more level.

If `Brand1` & `Brand2` are fixed and number of images will be upto 4 then you do not need dynamic query.If `number of brand` can be anything then one more sample data accordingly.

My Script is in `Sql server 2016+`,

```
drop table if exists #temp
create table #temp(RespondentsID varchar(10),Q_Brand_1 varchar(50),Q_Brand_2 varchar(40))
insert into #temp values
    ('001','2','1;2;3;4')
    ,('002','2;3','1')
    ,('003','1;4','1;2')

    ;with CTE as
    (
    select RespondentsID,oa.value1,Q_Brand_2 from #temp
    outer apply(select value as value1 from string_split(Q_Brand_1,';'))oa
    )
    ,CTE1 as
    (
    select RespondentsID,value1,value2 from cte
    outer apply(select value as value2 from string_split(Q_Brand_2,';'))oa
    )
    select 
    RespondentsID, [Brand_1_Imagery_1], [Brand_1_Imagery_2],[Brand_1_Imagery_3], [Brand_1_Imagery_4]
    ,cast(isnull([1],0) as bit) as [Brand_2_Imagery_1],cast(isnull([2],0) as bit) as [Brand_2_Imagery_2]
    ,cast(isnull([3],0) as bit) as [Brand_2_Imagery_3],cast(isnull([4],0) as bit) as [Brand_2_Imagery_4]
    from
    (
    select distinct RespondentsID,cast(isnull([1],0) as bit) as [Brand_1_Imagery_1]
    ,cast(isnull([2],0) as bit) as [Brand_1_Imagery_2]
    ,cast(isnull([3],0) as bit) as [Brand_1_Imagery_3],cast(isnull([4],0) as bit) as [Brand_1_Imagery_4],value2
    from
    (select RespondentsID,value1,value2 from CTE1 c )src
    pivot (max(value1) for value1 in([1],[2],[3],[4]))pvt
    )src1
    pivot(max(value2) for value2 in([1],[2],[3],[4]))pvt1
```

I have use `In Built string_split`, but you can use your own `split string` function.It is not hard to understand.